# Website on IIS works on localhost but not from outside/via IP

Tags: iis, web-server, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I just created a Windows VM on Azure and installed IIS on it. I created a simple HTML file which works if you enter localhost but it's not accessible via the server IP. I googled for a long time and tried different tutorials/suggestions without any success, here is a screenshot of my firewall: https://i.gyazo.com/9edcc5e384b8022a8863a3aa9cc28096.png

Does someone know what issue could be?

Comment: Are you allowing inbound HTTP traffic in your NSG?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should open TCP 80, 443 ports on Azure side using any Azure tools, for example Azure management portal. In classic portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) click your VM, click ENDPOINTS then ADD, STAND-ALONE ENDPOINT. In new portal (https://portal.azure.com) click your VM, Network Interfaces, click name of current network interface and then Network Security Group (NSG). In NSG you should create a rule that allows incoming traffic to required ports.